# What is the use of the forward slash in Java?

Tags: java

I'm updating an old Java application to work on modern operating systems, and a very common error throughout this program is the use of a forward slash in class names. It's almost like it's trying to be used as a way to differentiate between subclasses or something. I can't seem to find much information on this online, as this is either written in Java 3 or 4 and I've never programmed in Java before.

A few examples of its usage in this program:

```
final class classname/a0 implements ActionListener { // <----------- these lines
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }

final class classname/a1 implements ActionListener {
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }

final class classname/a2 implements ActionListener {
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

They all throw the error `- Syntax error on token "/", extends expected` and `- The type classname is already defined`

Any info on what this means so that I can start work on a solution to this?

Comment: That is not valid Java and has never been valid Java. There are two uses of the `/` character in Java: as the division operator and for opening a comment. (And, technically, as part of a string or char literal).

Comment: Yea that's just not enough closing braces as far as I can see. (i.e. learn basic syntax - this has nothing to do with comments or /)

Comment: or maybe there is something to do with decompilation in here? the slashes are where i would expect a $ to be, separating an outer class name from the inner class name.

Comment: @NathanHughes You may be right, I had to decompile the .jar file (with permission), as I was not sent the raw source files. That was a bit of a headache.

Comment: you can try removing everything from the start to including the slash then and see if that compiles. so change classname/a1 to a1. or read up on anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @ThomasCook I added the ```//``` marker to show where the error was occurring as a comment. I wasn't meaning to point out which symbol I was talking about.

Comment: @Sam The fact that this came from a decompiler is very relevant to the question. Because in that case the question isn't "why was this written this way?" but "why did the decompiler produce code looking this way?"

Comment: @NathanHughes Wow. I think you're right lol. The file names are just a0.java a1.java, etc. Must have been a decompilation thing which I'm new at. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Sam Seeing the code it also went through obfuscation, since we generally don't use 't' as class names and 'a' and 'k' as field names. You are losing a lot of semantical information and I strongly suggest you try to get the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
final class classname/a2 implements ActionListener
```

You cannot use `/` in an identifier in Java.

As far as I can remember, the syntactical rules for Java indentifiers are as follows:

- numbers and letters only
- cannot start an identifier with a number

In addition, as far as I can see, there are not enough closing braces to syntactically "close" each of the classes code definitions.

It should be like so (assuming no knowledge of the type `t`):

```
final class classnamea0 implements ActionListener {
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }
}

final class classnamea1 implements ActionListener {
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }
}

final class classnamea2 implements ActionListener {
  private final t a;
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
    this.a.a(this.a.k.a, true, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

If I had to hazard a guess, it looks like you've tried to reverse engineer some byte code to Java readable source code using a tool and it's showing you inner, compile time derived, anonymous implemenations of interfaces from the source code.

In other words the following Kotlin code:

```
interface Bar {
    fun bar()
}

class Foo {
    fun foo() {
        val bar = object : Bar() {
            override fun bar() { } 
        }   
    }
}
```

At compile time, this is turned into byte code where there is a named inner class of `Bar` (usually something like `Foo$Bar0`) which maps to the anonymous implementation of `Bar` in the Kotlin source of `Foo` class. In other words, an anonymous implementation in source code is turned into a named implementation in the compiled java byte code (which itself is JIT compiled at run time).

This guess I am making is based of the fact the resultant "Java" code in the OP is A) not valid, B) obfuscated and C) showing evidence of decompilation from byte code of anonymous interface/abstract class implementations in the original source code.

Looks like the original engineer didn't intend for the code to be so easily reverse engineered (you may need mapping files from byte code -> source code to properly decode the byte code into readable source - these are usually produced as a side effect of a build process and may or may not still exist as data somewhere).

I.e. we may need more context to properly help out here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As Thomas pointed out, the ```classname/``` must have been an artifact from decompilation. Deleting that part and just having the class name be ```a0```, ```a1```, etc. seems to have been the solution. A seemingly obvious one, but hey, now I know.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, it looks like you've reverse engineered some byte code to java using a tool and it's showing you lambdas from the source code as anonmyous classes of the class they were defined and invoked in from the original Java source code. This is based of the fact the resultant "Java" code is A) not valid and B) obfuscated. i.e. more context required. Looks like the original engineer didn't intend for the code to be so easily reverse engineered (you may need mapping files from source -> byte to properly decode the byte code into readable source)